# Vue radio button v-if with v-model

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I am very new to html and vue, and trying to create radio button. I use local JSON file which is being used for creating UI. I loop through JSON object and create radio buttons accordingly. I used "defaultedOptionId" to find which one to be checked as default. Here is my JSON:

```
{ "id": 1,
  "selected": 1,
  "defaultedOptionId": 2,
  "selections": [
    {
      "selectionId": 1,
      "description: "XX"
    },
    ...
}, 
...
```

I am using Vue component, which basically holds JSON file. In the template, I have code so when 'defaultedOptionId === selectionId', check as default

```
<p v-for="(selection, index) in choice.selections">
     <input v-if="choice.defaultOptionId === selection.selectionId" type="radio" :name="'option_' + choice.choiceId" :value="selection.selectionId" checked></input>
     <input v-else type="radio" :name="'option_' + choice.choiceId" :value="selection.selectionId"></input>
        {{ index+1 }}. {{ selection.description }}
```

'choice' is basically JSON object.

This works if I change defaultOptionId to something else. **HOWEVER, if I want to update JSON object as user selects radio button, I have to add v-model to the input field** like this:

```
<p v-for="(selection, index) in choice.selections">
     <input v-if="choice.defaultOptionId === selection.selectionId" type="radio" :name="'option_' + choice.choiceId" :value="selection.selectionId" v-model="choice.selectedOptionId" checked></input>
     <input v-else type="radio" :name="'option_' + choice.choiceId" :value="selection.selectionId" v-model="choice.selectedOptionId"></input>
        {{ index+1 }}. {{ selection.description }}
```

With this, radio buttons with 'checked' property doesn't work. It checks first option and even if I change 'defaultOptionId', it doesn't care.

Basically, **I want to load different JSON file with different 'defaultOptionId' which changes default check for radio button WHILE when user selects radio button, it updates JSON file's 'selectedOptionId'.** I can make it work separately, but not together. I have to use this design since other templates are following the same design.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do and what the problem is because the question looks like a mess, but I'll try to help anyway.

### Demo:

Here's a working example with your data:

https://codepen.io/AlekseiHoffman/pen/XWJmpod?editors=1010

### Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(selection, index) in choice.selections">
    <input 
      type="radio" 
      :id="selection.id" 
      :value="selection.selectionId" 
      v-model="choice.selected"
    >
    <label>
      {{selection.description}}
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    Selected: {{ choice.selected }}
  </div>
</div>
```

### Script:

```
choice: { 
  "id": 1,
  "selected": 2,
  "selections": [
    {
      "selectionId": 1,
      "description": "Radio One"
    },
    {
      "selectionId": 2,
      "description": "Radio Two"
    }
  ]
}
```

I simplified the JSON object since the other properties are not needed there to make it work.

Let me know if you're still having difficulties with your task.